# Fourier transform of integral related to zeta function

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, multiple-integral

In this MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/225327/24611), I asked about the Fourier transform of the zeta function. The second answer lists the following as a representation for $\zeta(s)$, with $E(x)$ as the floor function:

\begin{multline}
\zeta(\frac 1 2 +it)=-it\int_{1}^{+\infty}\bigl(x-E(x)\bigr)x^{-\frac3 2 -it }dx
-\frac 1 2\int_{1}^{+\infty}\bigl(x-E(x)\bigr)x^{-\frac3 2 -it }dx\\-\frac{1+2it}{1-2it},
\tag{$\ast$}
\end{multline}

The idea is that by getting the Fourier transform of the expression $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\bigl(x-E(x)\bigr)x^{-\frac3 2 -it }dx$, we can essentially get the whole thing.

To get this Fourier transform, we need to solve the double integral

$F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\int_{1}^{+\infty}\bigl(x-E(x)\bigr)x^{-\frac3 2 -it }dx \right] e^{-i\omega t} dt$

The answer then goes onto say:

> With the above formula, it is easy to find an explicit expression for the Fourier transform: in fact, we need only to calculate the Fourier transform of $t\mapsto e^{-it \ln x}$, which is $\delta_0(\tau+\frac{\ln x}{2π})$... As a result, the Fourier transform of the second term in $(\ast)$ is given by
>   $$
> \int_{1}^{+\infty}\bigl(x-E(x)\bigr)x^{-\frac3 2 }\delta_0(\tau+\frac{\ln x}{2π})dx,
> $$

I am somewhat at a loss for how to arrive at this result. How do you go from the double integral to this? It doesn't seem like you can flip the order of the integrals here since there's that $e^{-i\omega t}$ on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still interested in the question of obtaining the Fourier transform of Zeta w.r.t. the imaginary part inside the critical strip? I've been looking at a simpler approach to those suggested.

Comment: I am certainly interested and welcome to the site! FWIW, you may want to delete this "answer" and repost as a "comment" as answers are only supposed to be for answers. That being said, no need to ask if anyone is interested, I am still very curious what the answer is...